# Why do we have to specify -i when starting an interactive docker container but not the -t?

Tags: docker

I use docker as part of my education and we start containers with Linux images with the `-i` flag. Why do I not have to specify the `-t` flag when starting a container, but I have to specify both `-i` and `-t` when creating a new container with the `run` command?

as in:

```
docker start -i [container name]
```

vs

```
docker run -it ... (rest of the command)
```

Does a container just permanently have that pseudo-tty when you create it? And will it permanently not have one if the `-t` is not specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I not have to specify the `-t` flag when starting a container, but I have to specify both `-i` and `-t` when creating a new container with the `run` command?

First, I would argue that you don't have to specify `-i` when creating a container. The `-i` flag starts the container in interactive mode, but if you don't need to interact with the container, then not having the `-i` flag is perfectly fine. You might want to start a web server in a container in the background, and in that case you wouldn't use `-i`.

> And will it permanently not have one if the `-t` is not specified?

Correct. You can see this difference if you try running a program which has special behavior when connected to a tty:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu bash
root@b4c828502868:/#
```

However, if you start it without a tty, it won't show you a prompt.

```
$ docker run -i ubuntu bash
```

You can still type commands (it still has stdin, stdout, and stderr, even without `-t`) but it won't act like a normal tty.

Comment: I see now that I have to use the -it flags when using docker exec after restarting a container. How can it be it's not consistent with how we use the flags?